# Sending Mail using GWT Java in Dev mode

Tags: java, email, gwt, servlets

Can someone explain how to send mail in development mode from the gwt jetty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mode does not matter. The mail is sent on the server-side. You can use [commons-email](http://commons.apache.org/email/) to send emails from a servlet of yours. Check the [user guide](http://commons.apache.org/email/userguide.html) for a simple example. Note that you will need an SMTP server. For test purposes [you can use your google account](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287).

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing about GWT because it runs on the server-side (pure java code) and you can use all the api that written in java. Have a look at [java mail api](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/index.html)